# 左外部結合がうまくいきません。

Tags: spring, jpa, hibernate

結合でデータを取ろうとしているのですが、以下のような例外が起こります
この例外を回避する方法を知りたいです。

＜例外が状況＞
T_estimateにデータがある
T_estimate_detailsにデータがない

※両方データがある場合は例外は発生していません。

【実行しているJPQL】

```
select 
    new sel.T(
    t_e.esti_rep_no
    , t_ed.esti_rep_details_no) 
    from 
    T_estimate t_e left join t_e.t_estimate_details t_ed
```

【結果格納クラス】
    package sel;

```
public class T {
    private int esti_rep_no;    
    private int esti_rep_details_no;

        // アクセサメソッドは省略
}
```

【スタックトレース】

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: could not instantiate class [sel.T] from tuple
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class T {
    // private int esti_rep_no;    
    // private int esti_rep_details_no;

    private Integer esti_rep_no;    
    private Integer esti_rep_details_no;

    // アクセサメソッドは省略
}
```